# Where to put your patents/ patent pending info in software? And should you really do it?

Tags: gui-design, layout

My softare company has a few patents/ patent pendings. Does it make sense to showcase this in our products?

If so, where should we put it? In our splash screen? In the Help Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information of any software usually resides as Meta data of the application in an About box. There you *usually* find information of current installed version, license agreements and sometimes patents / patents pending information. I would put this information as a link to your patents / patents pending page on your web site, if users want to read more.

Accessing an About box from the HELP-menu is implemented in some of the major web browsers (Internet Explorer, Firefox and Opera). Other web browsers (Chrome and Safari) lets you access the same About box from the settings menu. But the About box itself contains the same information.

[image: Help menu of Internet Explorer 10]
[image: About box of Internet Explorer]
[image: About box of Firefox]
[image: About box of Chrome]

If it’s important that your users finds the patents / patents pending information, I see no reason not to link both from the SETTINGS menu and the HELP menu. Users have different mappings and preconceived meaning of how to reach the About box. Supporting both conventional ways to get there can only do well.